# DBUnit property is not used

Tags: java, dbunit

I have a JUnit testcase which uses a DBUnit connection. What I want is to set the DatatypeFactory to DB2 for z/OS which doesn't seem to exist, so I decided to suppress the warnings

`The configured data type factory 'class org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DefaultDataTypeFactory' might cause problems with the current database 'DB2 for DB2 UDB for z/OS' (e.g. some datatypes may not be supported properly). In rare cases you might see this message because the list of supported database products is incomplete (list=[derby]) [...]`

According to the manual, I added the last line:

```
@Before
private static void insertFromXML(IDataSet dataSet) throws Exception {
    databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester(JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD, SCHEMA);
    databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(DatabaseOperation.INSERT);
    databaseTester.setDataSet(dataSet);
    databaseTester.onSetup();
    databaseTester.getConnection().getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_DATATYPE_WARNING, false);
}
```

But still I get the warnings and don't understand why. If somehow I can link a DatatypeFactory for `DB2 for DB2 UDB for z/OS` that would also solve the problem, maybe `setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new Db2DataTypeFactory());` is working but deals with the same problem as disabling the warnings.

Thanks in advance